# How to configure SendGrid Sender Authentication (Domain Verification) in GoDaddy

Tags: sendgrid, godaddy-api

Unable to validate the domain with GoDaddy after adding the CNAMEs from SendGrid

Answer (score 62):

This was a simple fix. SendGrid asks you to add 3 CNAMES(5 CNAMES if branding needs to be enabled) for domain verification on your DNS Management Portal. Issue was that I was adding the entire CNAME which SendGrid was providing me, but GoDaddy just expects only the individual name, it appends the domain name to the CNAME during domain name resolution.

So for example, if SendGrid asks you to add something like below as a CNAME in GoDaddy,

- ex0123.sub.domain.com, you should be adding only ex0123
- for s1._domainkey.sub.domain.com you should be adding only s1._domainkey as the
- For s2._domainkey.domain.com add only s2._domainkey

This fixed my issue, hope this helps you as well!

Comment: OMG I know this is against the rulz, but man I LOVE YOU.... keep it safe Sreepriya

Comment: How you even knew that :O ? I've more than 4 days and a lot of lost clients trying to fix this

Comment: You are a legend.  Why can't they standardize this stuff.

Comment: This works! This should be the accepted answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: Back here for a 2nd time as I forgot.  Thanks again!

Comment: Back here for a second time !! Thanks again

Comment: This works with GoDaddy and the documentation in SendGrid should reflect your answer

Comment: I found this was the case for Google Domains as well, where the domain is automatically appended to whatever you enter into the host field.

Comment: does this work for namecheap?

Comment: Same answer for NameCheap. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I struggled for a day and found [this doc](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/troubleshooting-sender-authentication#auto-appending) which says:-

> Some DNS hosts will automatically add your top-level domain to the end of DNS records you create, which can turn a CNAME for “email.domain.com” into “email.domain.com.domain.com”. Be sure to follow the convention on existing records in your DNS panel when adding new ones, as sometimes you will only need to add what is to the left of the top-level domain.

For example, a `CNAME` for `“email.”` becomes `“email.domain.com”`

In Godaddy, you dont have to put domain name in `CNAME` records, just put the subdomain. **Also, you need to put the entire `VALUE` string provided by Sendgrid in `value` field in Godaddy.** as of Sep 2021.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62531377/3744182) by [Sreepriya Sreekumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8978623/sreepriya-sreekumar) worked perfectly but as of May 2021 in Godaddy I had to keep the full s2._domainkey.domain.com then it worked.

Steps 1 and 2 are exactly as written in that answer.

Comment: It worked for me